# Isomorphism relation in $Hom(\mathbb{Z}_6,\mathbb{R}^*\oplus\mathbb{C}^*)?$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism

Let $\mathbb{R}^*$ and $\mathbb{C}^*$ are multiplicative group of real number and complex number relatively. 
what group does isomorphism with
$$Hom(\mathbb{Z}_6,\mathbb{R}^*\oplus\mathbb{C}^*)?$$

Comment: Hint: the image of $0\in\mathbb{Z}_6$ must be an element of order divisor of 6. In $\mathbb{R}^*$ there are only two such elements and in $\mathbb{C}^*$ there are the six-th roots of unity.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: @Javi Surely you meant the image  of $1$, not $0$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich absolutely, I guess I didn't know what I was typing

Comment: Does  $\mathbb{C}^* $ have six roots at this state? So the answer is group with 12 elements?

Comment: @Ruhi.Js there is more than one group (up to isomorphism) with 12 elements, so you have to decide which of them.